# static assignment calling the method twice

Tags: java, static

*Hmmm... I m not able to come up with a better title for this question*

I m not able to understand why calling a static method and assigning it's value to another static member is calling the method `getValue()` twice.

If I move the static assignment after `main` method, it is not loading twice.
I know this is stupid, but am I missing something obvious?

```
public class Test {
    private static Integer value1 = getValue(); // This is causing to load again

    private static Integer flag = null;

    public static Integer getValue() {
        if (flag != null) { // if flag is loaded already, return it.
            return flag;
        }

        System.out.println("Loading value...");

        flag = Integer.valueOf(10);

        return flag;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getValue();
    }

    private static Integer value2 = getValue(); // This will not cause to load again
}
```

Output:

```
Loading value...
Loading value...
```

Test online: https://ideone.com/pgRbff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's step through a few key lines.

This line:

```
private static Integer value1 = getValue();
```

prints "Loading value..." and sets `flag` to a non-null value.

Then this line:

```
private static Integer flag = null;
```

sets `flag` *back to `null`*.

Then this line:

```
private static Integer value2 = getValue();
```

prints "Loading value..." again and sets `flag` to a non-null value again.

Then `main` runs, and this line:

```
getValue();
```

doesn't print anything, because `flag` is set to a non-null value.

Comment: This is correct. OP, you can verify this by swapping the declarations of `value1` and `flag`, and noting that "Loading value..." is only printed once.

Comment: @Kamal:  This has nothing to do with the evils of static variables.  This is just a design smell.

Comment: Aaahh.. I knew I m being stupid here... How did I miss it... My head is showing signs of deprived sleep... lol... Thanks again...

Answer (score -2):

This is good question. Classloader follow some rule to load a class, static statements load first and create memory for that at class area in heap memory.